# Pad out array with "0" if length less than

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that `split` from `.` in the string:

Input data: `1.2.3.4.5.6`

Output data: `["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]`

However, the input data can be any numbers up to 6 items for the output (`1` or `1.2.3`).

I was trying to figure out what is the easiest way to pad the array out to 6 items in the array if less than the maximum?

I tried `concat`ing them, but that just appends `["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]` to the end, and without a key value I'm not sure how to match them.

So in the above, if the input was `1` the output would be `["1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]`. If the input was `1.2.3.4` the output would be `["1", "2", "3", "4", "0", "0"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Appending a zero-filled array to the end and then slicing the first 6 items would work:

```js
const input = '4.5.6';

const output = input
  .split('.')
  .concat(new Array(6).fill(0).map(String))
  .slice(0, 6);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: i was so close, just select the first 6 - thank you and simple

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.from` and `??` (nullish coalesce operator) or `||`

```js
const input = '3.4.5';

const nums = input.split('.');
const res = Array.from({length: 6}, (_, i) => nums[i] ?? "0")

console.log(res)
```